# Cannot increase open file limit beyond 999999 on 14.04+

Tags: ulimit, resource-limiting

I'm trying to increase open file limit for root user as well as non-root user via `/etc/security/limits.conf`. But, cannot get past `999999`, anything above this value reverts to default `1024` nor I can set it to unlimited

Here is my `limits.conf`

```
* hard nofile 999999
* hard nofile 999999
root hard nofile 999999
root soft nofile 999999
```

The above works fine and `ulimit -n` return `999999`.

But, if I make the value one step higher or to `unlimited` or `-1` or `infinity` it  doesn't work. `ulimit -n` return `1024`

I refered here: [limits.conf - configuration file for the pam_limits module | Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/limits.conf.5.html)

Thanks

Comment: What is your real problem?

Comment: Hi Jos, let me make it simple for you. Thought the pam_limits documentation says `All items support the values -1, unlimited or infinity indicating no limit, except for priority and nice.` I can't set `unlimited` to nofile, if I do so `ulimit -n` returns 1024, not sure if this is an expected behaviour

Comment: Do you really need more than a million files open?

Comment: Its a development machine with Kafka and Zookeeper, openfiles tend to grow with Topics and number of partitions.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's 10 months late, but you've set the hard limit twice for all users.  Change the second line to be a soft ulimit.

```
* hard nofile 999999
* soft nofile 999999
root hard nofile 999999
root soft nofile 999999
```

After doing this you should see:

```
$ ulimit -n
999999
$
```

Your file should have always worked for root as the limits were correctly defined.

Furthermore you can't use -1, infinity, unlimited or the like, you must use a literal value.  The max supported value for this is defined in the kernel and is exposed in /proc/sys/fs/nr_open.  In my centos 7 & debian strech environments I get the same value:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
1048576
$
```

You also have to start a new session for the limits to update.

Answer (score 0):

There are three files to modify to get this to work:

- `/etc/security/limits.conf`
- `/etc/pam.d/common-session`
- `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`

You have already added the required lines in the first file, then in the other two files this line is needed:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Please note:

> The thing that most resources neglect to emphasize, is that your limits can really easily be modified by anything responsible for execution of your processes. If ulimit -n (run as the correct user) is giving you the number you just set, but cat /proc/{process_id}/limits is still printing the low number, you almost certainly have a process manager, an init script, or something similar messing your limits up. You also need to keep in mind that processes inherit the limits of the parent process.

Hence if such a process exists then you will have to modify the config file to get it to work.

Source:
 https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors

Comment: Thanks George. I understand all the above. The issue here is setting it to `unlimted` is not working. I mean setting that in upstart, systemd scripts of the process as well.